# Rails ActionController: Difference between request.remote_ip and request.remote_addr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, client, request, ip-address, actioncontroller

In the ActionController source, local requests are defined as follows:

```
def local_request? #:doc:
    request.remote_addr == LOCALHOST && request.remote_ip == LOCALHOST
end
```

In my application, I want to use different logic if requests are coming from a particular IP range. What is the difference between `request.remote_addr` and `request.remote_ip`, and which one should I use?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm the author of the current implementation of `remote_ip`, and the other things that it does include checking for IP spoofing attacks, and correctly handling multiple `X-Forwarded-For` headers. There's a big caveat, though: only some Ruby web servers support multiple headers, so the value still might be wrong.

I wrote up the results from testing the most popular Ruby app servers [on my blog](http://andre.arko.net/2011/12/26/repeated-headers-and-ruby-web-servers/), which you might want to check out if repeated headers matter for your application.

Answer (score 11):

It seems to be the case that `remote_addr` returns the value of the `REMOTE_ADDR` environment variable as-is, while `remote_ip` will adjust this based on the presence of `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` and `HTTP_CLIENT_IP` variables as well, such as you might have when your client is being forwarded through a proxy.

That double check for `local_request?` is simply a way of ascertaining that the user came from a local machine, and wasn't simply forwarded from somewhere else through a local proxy.